# Group By Issue in Select Query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am kind of stuck in one of the SQL queries where I would require little help.

Table structure is as follow:

Table #1: `PROD_ORDER`:

```
ID_PROD_ORDER(PK)
1001                   
1002              
1003
```

Table #2: `JOB`

```
ID_JOB | ID_PROD_ORDER(FK)|ID_ASSET | DT_START            | DT_END
1          1001               8       2016/11/22 05:45:50   2016/11/24 13:13:14
2          1001               8       some date             some date
3          1002               9       some date             some date
4          1002               9       some date             some date
5          1003               8       some date             some date
6          1001               8       some date             some date
```

Table #3: `Confirmation`

```
ID_CONFIRMATION | ID_JOB | QT_CONF | QT_SCRAP
```

Table #4: `DOWNTIME`

```
ID_DOWNTIME | DT_START | DT_END | ID_ORG_SUB_ASSET
```

Now the requirement is to find order and

- Start date of the order (which will be Min of DT_START from JOB)
- End date of the order (which will be Max of DT_END from JOB)
- Sum of all of its jobs' QT_CONF
- Sum of all of its jobs' QT_SCRAP
- Downtime from DOWNTIME table where downtime = Difference in seconds of DT_START - DT_END

`ID_ASSET`, `Start Date` and `End Date` will be passed in as parameters.

I have written this query:

```
SELECT
    PO.ID_PROD_ORDER,
    J.ID_ORG_ASSET,
    SUM(C.QT_CONF) AS "QT_CONF",
    SUM(C.QT_SCRAP) AS "QT_SCRAP",
    MIN(J.DT_JOB_ST) AS "START_DATE",
    MAX(J.DT_JOB_ED) AS "END_DATE",
    (SELECT SUM(datediff(ss, D.DT_START, D.DT_END)) AS "DOWNTIMESECONDS"  
     FROM DOWNTIME D
     INNER JOIN SUB_ASSET SA ON D.ID_SUB_ASSET = SA.ID_SUB_ASSET
     WHERE SA.ID_ASSET = [Param.3] AND D.DT_START >= J.DT_JOB_ST 
       AND D.DT_END <= J.DT_JOB_ED) 
FROM
    PROD_ORDER PO
INNER JOIN 
    JOB J ON PO.ID_PROD_ORDER = J.ID_PROD_ORDER 
          AND J.DT_JOB_ST >= '[Param.1]' 
          AND J.DT_JOB_ED <= '[Param.2]'
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CONFIRMATION C ON C.ID_JOB = J.ID_JOB
WHERE
    J.ID_ASSET = [Param.3] 
GROUP BY 
    PO.ID_PROD_ORDER, J.ID_ASSET
```

The query throws an error:

> JOB.DT_JOB_ST cannot be included in select list as it is not used in aggregation or GROUP BY

If I put `JOB.DT_JOB_ST` and `JOB.DT_JOB_ED` in `GROUP BY`, then it returns more than 1 row for each order but I need only one row per order.

How can I correct it? I'm just confused !!

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the query to remove the need for the correlated query?

Comment: Try `AND D.DT_START >= MIN(J.DT_JOB_ST) 
       AND D.DT_END <= MAX(J.DT_JOB_ED))`. Btw, you use `J.ID_ORG_ASSET` in `SELECT`, but `J.ID_ASSET` in `GROUP`, this should also fail.

Comment: AND D.DT_START >= MIN(J.DT_JOB_ST) AND D.DT_END <= MAX(J.DT_JOB_ED)) worked ! .. Thanks a ton . .How can I give points to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query worked :

```
SELECT
    PO.ID_PROD_ORDER,
    J.ID_ASSET,
    SUM(C.QT_CONF) AS "QT_CONF",
    SUM(C.QT_SCRAP) AS "QT_SCRAP",
    MIN(J.DT_JOB_ST) AS "START_DATE",
    MAX(J.DT_JOB_ED) AS "END_DATE",
    (SELECT SUM(datediff(ss, D.DT_START, D.DT_END)) AS "DOWNTIMESECONDS"  
     FROM DOWNTIME D
     INNER JOIN SUB_ASSET SA ON D.ID_SUB_ASSET = SA.ID_SUB_ASSET
     WHERE SA.ID_ASSET = [Param.3] AND D.DT_START >= MIN(J.DT_JOB_ST) 
       AND D.DT_END <= MAX(J.DT_JOB_ED)) 
FROM
    PROD_ORDER PO
INNER JOIN 
    JOB J ON PO.ID_PROD_ORDER = J.ID_PROD_ORDER 
          AND J.DT_JOB_ST >= '[Param.1]' 
          AND J.DT_JOB_ED <= '[Param.2]'
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CONFIRMATION C ON C.ID_JOB = J.ID_JOB
WHERE
    J.ID_ASSET = [Param.3] 
GROUP BY 
    PO.ID_PROD_ORDER, J.ID_ASSET
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue here is the correlated query, which will try to evaluate for each row - as this includes the `DT_JOB_ST` and `DT_JOB_ED` it would need these to be part of the group.

The other option would be to rewrite to not need the correlated query, so something like this should be good for you:

```
SELECT      PO.ID_PROD_ORDER,
            J.ID_ORG_ASSET,
            SUM(C.QT_CONF) AS [QT_CONF],
            SUM(C.QT_SCRAP) AS [QT_SCRAP],
            MIN(J.DT_JOB_ST) AS [START_DATE],
            MAX(J.DT_JOB_ED) AS [END_DATE],
            SUM(ISNULL(datediff(ss, D.DT_START, D.DT_END),0)) AS [DOWNTIMESECONDS]

FROM        PROD_ORDER PO

INNER JOIN  JOB J 
    ON      PO.ID_PROD_ORDER = J.ID_PROD_ORDER 
    AND     J.DT_JOB_ST >= '[Param.1]' 
    AND     J.DT_JOB_ED <= '[Param.2]'

LEFT JOIN   CONFIRMATION C
    ON      C.ID_JOB = J.ID_JOB

LEFT JOIN   DOWNTIME D
    INNER JOIN  SUB_ASSET SA
        ON      D.ID_SUB_ASSET = SA.ID_SUB_ASSET
        AND     SA.ID_ASSET = [Param.3]
    ON      D.DT_START >= J.DT_JOB_ST 
    AND     D.DT_END <= J.DT_JOB_ED

WHERE       J.ID_ASSET = [Param.3] 

GROUP BY    PO.ID_PROD_ORDER, J.ID_ORG_ASSET
```

(if you prefer, a CTE could work, too)

Comment: This does not give correct output. It seems this query calculates SUM(C.QT_CONF) , SUM(C.QT_SCRAP) and SUM of Downtime of all entries possible(which should not be included) and gives a very high number.